# Line and word counter function not adding up correctly C++

Tags: c++, function, counter

This program is supposed to tell the user how many words and lines are in their program (text file only). The two functions that I have written both work, except the num_of_lines function is counting one more line than is correct every time and the num_of_words function is off by about 300 words every time. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks. I copy and pasted an output after my code and compared it to wc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#define die(errmsg) {cerr << errmsg << endl; exit(1);} 
using namespace std;

int num_of_words(string name)
{
    int cnt2 = 0;

    ifstream iwords;
    iwords.open(name);

    string w;
    if(iwords.is_open())
    {
        while(iwords >> w)
        {
            cnt2++;
        }
    }   
    else cerr <<"can not open" + name << endl;      
    iwords.close();
    return(cnt2);
}

int num_of_lines(string name)
{
    int cnt3 = 0;
    string line;

    ifstream ilines;     

    ilines.open(name);        

    if(ilines.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(ilines, line))
        {
            cnt3++;
        }   
    }  
    else cerr <<"can not open" + name << endl;
    ilines.close(); 
    return(cnt3);
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    int num_of_lines(string name);

    if(argc == 1)die("usage: mywc your_file"); 

    string file;
    file = argv[1];

    ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open(file);

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        int b;

        b = num_of_words(file);

        cout <<"Words: " << b << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr <<"Could not open: " << file << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    ifs.close();

    return(0);
}

Zacharys-MBP:c++ Zstow$ my sample.txt 
Chars: 59526
Words: 1689
Lines: 762
Zacharys-MBP:c++ Zstow$ wc sample.txt
     761    2720   59526 sample.txt
Zacharys-MBP:c++ Zstow$
```

Comment: What does the file look like?  Is it of by 300 with a single line file?

Comment: It's best practice not to put code on the same line as your while loop in C++.

Comment: Can we get an example of a line of "words" and the number of "words" your program calculates it to have?

Comment: It's for text file only and the results are the same for a single line file.

Comment: I copy and pasted the output and compared it to wc, so you can see how much it is off by. I guess words is off by more like 700- 800.

Comment: I would need to see an actual line and the word count for that line along with it to know what's going on.

Comment: With some thought, you could do the word and line counting in one pass.  For example read a line into a string (since you read a line, increment the line counter).  Next, parse the string for words, you could use `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Most files (especially programs) will end in a new line. You may not see this in your editor but it is probably there. You will have to check the last line to see if it actually contains any content, or if it is empty.

The istream operator (>>) will detect any group of characters between whitespace to be a "word." So if you're parsing programs, you may have:

```
for(int i=1; i<73; i++)
```

The istream operator will see 4 words: [`for(int`, `i=1;`, `i<73;`, `i++)`]

Comment: I would guess that `getline()` would return a string that is empty if the line is empty.  Just a thought, you may want to check this. :-)

Comment: if(getline(ilines, line) == " ")cnt3--;  I tried this, yet got compiling erros, not sure how to format it.

Comment: if(!getline(ilines, line))cnt3--; and this, yet it cuts the lines in half.